# Typescript: Expect Object or Boolean(false)

Tags: typescript

I have an api response that will return either:

```
geoblocked: false
```

or

```
geoblocked: {
  country: {
      id: number;
    }
}
```

I thought the interface for the above would be as simple as

```
export interface Country {
  country: {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    countryCode: string;
  };
}
export interface SiteDataType {
  geoblocked: Country | boolean;
}
```

However, with the above interface I am getting a type error when country exists. How can I expect type of boolean false?

Comment: Maybe try `geoblocked: Country | false;`

Comment: I tried this, however false is not a type

Comment: Can you put in the error you're getting? Looks like your interface expects `name` and `countryCode` which your response doesn't have

Comment: I'm with James.

Comment: @James (OP): [Boolean `false` is a type, though](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types): "There’s one more kind of literal type: boolean literals. There are only two boolean literal types, and as you might guess, they are the types `true` and `false`. The type boolean itself is actually just an alias for the union `true | false`."

Comment: What type error do you get exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is not with boolean one, is with the Country interface:

With these interfaces:

```js
export interface Country {
  country: {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    countryCode: string;
  };
}
export interface SiteDataType {
  geoblocked: Country | boolean;
}
```

Those objects are ok:

```js
let myvar: SiteDataType = {
    geoblocked: false
}

myvar = {
    geoblocked: {
        country: {
            id: 1,
            name: "hi",
            countryCode: "ES"
        }
    }
}
```

But this object is not valid:

```js
myvar = {
    geoblocked: {
        country: {
            id: 1
        }
    }
}
```

because both name and countryCode are required. So try with this interface for `Country`, to make not required both `name` and `countryCode` just adding a `?` to the properties:

```js
export interface Country {
  country: {
    id: number;
    name?: string;
    countryCode?: string;
  };
}
```

and of course, if `true` is not a valid type for `geoblocked` you can also set it on `false` or `Country`:

```js
export interface SiteDataType {
  geoblocked: Country | false;
}
```